# Implementing Marker Interfaces in Java

Tags: java

I want to implement a marker interface that suggests user to define a value like `serialVersionUID` that is suggested when a Class implements `java.io.Serializable`.
How can I achieve it in Java?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I don't think this is possible due to custom interfaces. Serializable is included in Java API and compiler can interpret it like so.

Comment: If you can go the annotation way - you can define a custom annotation with a (required) element

Comment: The feature you mention is implemented by IDEs, not by the marker interface itself.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev Zarev Could you please post an example or refer me a link on impolementing an annotation with a require element

Comment: @Ramu see the examples: http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/06/09/complete-java-annotations-tutorial/ The elements that do not have a default value are "required"

Comment: @SvetlinZarev Post the comment with the link as answer I shall mark it as correct and close the question.

Comment: @Ramu Done. I've added it as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can go the annotation way you can implement a custom annotation with a (required) element. Elements that do not have a *default* value are *required*.

For instance look at the following annotation:

```
public @interface Deprecated {
    String version(); //In which version this was deprecated?
    String reason() default "[not documented]";
}
```

Here `version` is a required field, while you can omit the `reason` field when annotating something.

For more information, you can look at this tutorial:
http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/06/09/complete-java-annotations-tutorial/